# python watchdog observe certain files but all directories

Tags: python, python-watchdog

I need to observe files of type, say `.tsv` but also need to observe all events on `directories`.

Currently, with the `patterns` argument, this is ignoring directories.

I want it to observe every event on `directories`.

Here's my code:

```
import time, sys
from watchdog.observers import Observer  
from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler
from datetime import datetime
import os
class MyHandler(PatternMatchingEventHandler):
    patterns = ["*.tsv"]
    ignore_patterns = []
    ignore_directories = False
    case_sensitive = True

def process(self, event):
    log_file = open('log.txt', 'a')
    path = os.path.join(event.src_path)
    line = path + "\t" + event.event_type + "\t" + str(datetime.now()) + "\n"
    log_file.write(line)
    log_file.close()

def on_created(self, event):
    self.process(event)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = sys.argv[1:]
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(MyHandler(), path=args[0] if args else '.', recursive=True)
    observer.start()

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    observer.stop()

observer.join()
```

How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Instead of using the pattern just configure the directory and when the event is triggered what you do is check the src_path to see if it is a .tsv file then you can implement whatever logic you need at this point...